# twilio_view decorator in twilio-django always giving 403

Tags: python, django, heroku, twilio

I have the following function in a Django view:

```
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view

@twilio_view
def index(request):
     twim = "<Response><Message>Hello World!</Message></Response>"
     return HttpResponse(twim, content_type='text/html')
```

It's accessed through the 'http://www.foo.com/bar' route. I have my Twilio account set to POST to that. Every time I send an sms I get a 403 error.

It works fine in debug mode, or when `DJANGO_TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION` is set to False, so I'm reasonably certain `twilio_view` isn't validating it properly. It gets the right URI (`request.build_absolute_uri()` gives the same path as the test client) and has the proper AUTH token, too. I've pretty much checked everything I could short of manually calculating the `TWILIO_SIGNATURE`, which I don't think I have the skill to do. Are there any obvious Django/Heroku/Twilio pitfalls I'm missing?

Comment: Possibly related by also unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755841/twilio-requestvalidator-for-python-always-returns-false

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of django-twilio library. First things first, what version of django-twilio are you using?

Run pip freeze to check:

```
$ pip freeze
...
django-twilio==0.7.1
```

I'd recommend upgrading to 0.7.1 and trying that out and seeing if it fixes the problem.
I did just push out an update related to this, so it might fix it.

Can you please open an [issue on github](https://github.com/rdegges/django-twilio/issues) in case this is a larger problem?

EDIT: The bug introduced in 0.7.1 means you should revert back to 0.7 with pip:

```
$ pip uninstall django-twilio
...
$ pip install django-twilio==0.7
```

Comment: Hey! I'm using 0.7.1 for django-twilio and 3.6.6 for twilio. I'll open an issue right now.

Comment: It looks like I'm running Django 1.6, though, and I *don't* have South, so that might be it. I'll see what happens after I update.